# Get destination from URL shortener via AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url-shortener, response-headers

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $.ajax({
       type: 'HEAD',
       url:'http://bit.ly/1vtp41Q',
       complete: function(request, textStatus){
            alert(request.getResponseHeader('Location'));
       }
    });
});
```

I'm making this AJAX call to get the header info from a bit.ly link. I can see the final destination under the Location header (checking it via the Console in Firebug on Firefox 33), but the getResponseHeader function is returning null.

Is it possible to get the URL and possibly the page's title by tweaking this code?

Comment: I'm guessing this violates the [**Same Origin Policy**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: Yes,it violates Same Origin Policy, see it in browser console http://jsfiddle.net/nNwGL/1/

Comment: No, it's not possible like this way.